# Accordions within accordions; how to make sortable only drag the data and not the accordions themselves

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have two lists that can exchange data between themselves. One of my lists is a list of accordions where you have space to drop your data, but also contain more specific accordions that also allow dropping data within them. I am able to drag and drop the data between the tables, and even within the accordions inside accordions, but here's the problem: I can also drag whole accordions too.

Here's the picture of my page:

[image: Buggy sortable]

I want to be able to sort between items inside an accordion without including the sub-accordions that they contain. Here's my Jquery functions:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#catalog").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false });
        $(".subcatalog").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, autoHeight: false });

        $(".SpecificCatalog").sortable({
            connectWith: ".ui-widget-content, .GeneralCatalog", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
        $(".ui-widget-content").sortable({
            connectWith: ".SpecificCatalog, .GeneralCatalog", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
        $(".GeneralCatalog").sortable({
            connectWith: ".SpecificCatalog, .ui-widget-content", helper: "clone",
            appendTo: "body",
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //console.log((this).sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'value' }));
                console.log(ui.item);
                console.log(ui.item.text());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here's my HTML(it contains logic to dynamically create the accordions):

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="ListaCodigos">
        <h2 class="ui-widget-header">CodigoAgrupador</h2>
        <div id="products">
            <div id="catalog">
                @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
                {
                    if (unchecked(double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) == (int)double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador)))
                    {
                        <h3><a href="#">@c.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c.NombreCuenta</a></h3>
                        <div>
                            <div class="subcatalog">
                                @foreach (CodigoAgrupadorCuentas_CE c2 in Model.CodigosAgrupadores)
                                {
                                    if (double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) > double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) && double.Parse(c2.CodigoAgrupador) < (double.Parse(c.CodigoAgrupador) + 1))
                                    {
                                        <h4><a href="#">@c2.CodigoAgrupador  -  @c2.NombreCuenta</a></h4>
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="SpecificCatalog">
                                                <ol>
                                                    <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                                </ol>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="GeneralCatalog">
                                <ol>
                                    <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart">
        <h2 class="ui-widget-header">Catalogos</h2>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            @foreach (LedgerChartOfAccounts c in Model.Catalogos)
            {
                if (c.CodigoAgrupador == null)
                {
                    <ul>
                        <li class="draggable">@c.GLAccountNumber  - @c.GLAccountName  </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <footer>Inserte los catalogos en el grupo que pertenescan, jale.</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried adding more divisions within the contains with different ids, in order to specify certain area to be sortable, but I still can't seem to get it right. Any help is welcome.

**EDIT:** I have come to the conclusion that I need to use different separators/classes with my divs in order to make this work the way I want it to be, but I'm stuck in finding a way to make things still stay close to the same format, while at the same time, working as intended with the accordions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it after getting a good night sleep and taking a good look at the code. it turns out this class here: ".ui-widget-content" was the problem all along.

By using this for my jquery function connection, I was actually including everything within any accordion as a sortable, which is  why I had plenty of "bugs" and "glitches" even if I used multiple div classes to separate elements.

On my second list, I changed my div class from

```
  <div id="ui-widget-content">
```

to

```
<div id="codigosAgrupadores>
```

and changed the code in the jquery function to reflect the changes.